# What is the difference of these two ways in bash?

Tags: bash

What is the difference between these two?

1. Using `&&` and `||`:

   ```
   command1 && command2 || command3
   ```
2. Using `if` and `else`:

   ```
   if command1  
   then  
       command2  
   else  
       command3  
   fi
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, command3 will be executed if either command1 or command2 fail: if command1 passes but command2 fails, command3 will be executed. In the if-then-else example, command3 will be executed only when command1 fails.

In other words, the first one, when translated into if-then-else becomes:

```
if command1
then
    if !command2
    then
        command3
    fi
else
    command3
fi
```

With command1=true, command2=false and command3=echo 'something' you can see the difference. The `&&-||` version:

```
true && false || echo 'something'
```

will yield `something` as output. When using the `if-then-else` version:

```
if true
then
    false
else
    echo 'something'
fi
```

you'll have no output.

Comment: Suddenly remembered I have done scripts like this. I even drew a flow chart to see.

Answer (score 4):

The latter will always work <s>properly</s>intuitively. The former has a boundary condition where both `command2` and `command3` can be executed.

Comment: The two examples behave differently, that's clear. Which one behaves "properly" and which one is buggy of course depends on what the intended meaning was!

Comment: I'm being a bit argumentative here, but I don't think "intuitively" is a better word. Consider `is_feature_enabled && run_feature || notify_feature_failed`: it is both intuitive and correct but the `if/then/else/fi` version is neither intuitive nor correct.

Comment: I guess it's true that nested `if`s would be more readable. +1

Comment: The two examples mean semantically a different thing, so it is not a question of readability. Check my answer for details.